# What C# SMPP client to use?

Tags: client, smpp

I have registered jamaa SmppClient

```
        SmppClient client = new SmppClient();

        SmppConnectionProperties properties = client.Properties;
        properties.SystemID = "uname";
        properties.Password = "pass";
        properties.Port = 2775; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = "ip"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = "mysystemtype";
        properties.DefaultServiceType = "mydefaultservicetype";

        //Resume a lost connection after 30 seconds
        client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;

        //Send Enquire Link PDU every 15 seconds
        client.KeepAliveInterval = 15000;

        //Start smpp client
        client.Start();
        //client.ConnectionStateChanged += client_ConnectionStateChanged;

        TextMessage msg = new TextMessage();

        msg.DestinationAddress = "number"; //Receipient number
        msg.SourceAddress = "number"; //Originating number
        msg.Text = "Hello, this is my test message!";
        msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = true; //I want delivery notification for this message

        //SmppClient client = GetSmppClient();
        client.SendMessage(msg);
```

But I'm getting

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in JamaaTech.Smpp.Net.Client.v1.4.dll

is Jamaa forking?

[jamaa-smpp]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some delays in your code after when you new the `SmppClient` instance is created and after when you start the `Client`.

```
SmppClient client = new SmppClient();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

and

```
client.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

The reason is connecting is done via an async method and your command to send a message hits it too soon.